# pyaudio on Ubuntu 12.04 Invalid input device

Tags: python, ubuntu-12.04, pyaudio

This is similar to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4672155/pyaudio-ioerror-no-default-input-device-available), but I can't get PyAudio to work with the EPD or system installation.

```
In 1: import pyaudio
In [2]: pa = pyaudio.PyAudio()
In [3]: pa.get_default_input_device_info()
IOError                                   Traceback (most recent call last)
 in ()
----> 1 pa.get_default_input_device_info()
```

/usr/local/epd/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PyAudio-0.2.4-py2.7-linux-i686.egg/pyaudio.pyc in get_default_input_device_info(self)
    933         """
    934 
--> 935         device_index = pa.get_default_input_device()
    936         return self.get_device_info_by_index(device_index)
    937

IOError: No Default Input Device Available

Or with the system install:

```
>>> import pyaudio
>>> pa = pyaudio.PyAudio()
>>> pa.get_default_input_device_info()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 1, in 
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pyaudio.py", line 935, in get_default_input_device_info
    device_index = pa.get_default_input_device()
IOError: No Default Input Device Available
```

Any idea as to how to fix this to get PyAudio working?