# PyAudio no default output device

Tags: python, ubuntu, pyaudio

I'm having trouble getting pyaudio working on an Ubuntu machine (trusty).  Trying to use the blocking wave-player code on the pyaudio documentation page I get:

```
Cannot connect to server socket err = No such file or directory
Cannot connect to server request channel
jack server is not running or cannot be started
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "./pyaudio-play.py", line 22, in <module>
   output=True)
 File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pyaudio.py", line 747, in open
   stream = Stream(self, *args, **kwargs)
 File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pyaudio.py", line 442, in __init__
   self._stream = pa.open(**arguments)
IOError: [Errno Invalid output device (no default output device)] -9996
```

Like  [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4672155/pyaudio-ioerror-no-default-input-device-available%20this) post, I have no devices available, but I'm not using enthought as far as I know.  Typing pyaudio.pa.__file__ returns

> '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/_portaudio.so'

And I just installed libportaudio-dev and libportaudio0 via apt-get.

For what it's worth, arecord and aplay don't pick up devices either:

```
aplay -l
aplay: device_list:268: no soundcards found...
```

But they both seem to work anyway (i.e. the one records and the other plays).

I DO have devices registering

$ cat /proc/asound/cards

```
 0 [PCH            ]: HDA-Intel - HDA Intel
PCH
                      HDA Intel PCH at 0xf9120000 irq 81  1 [NVidia         ]: HDA-Intel - HDA NVidia
                      HDA NVidia at 0xfb080000 irq 36  2 [Mic            ]: USB-Audio - Samson Meteor Mic
                      Samson Technologies Samson Meteor Mic at usb-0000:00:1d.0-1.1, full speed  3 [NVidia_1       ]: HDA-Intel - HDA
NVidia
                      HDA NVidia at 0xf9080000 irq 44
```

(Sorry about the newlines not working correctly in this post)

Any ideas?

Comment: I installed portaudio-dev19 and that seemed to work but when I logged back in I was back to the same problem.  Strange.

Answer (score 1):

Had to install portaudio19-dev.  This seemed to work for a minute then it broke again.

It looks like the sounds system got mucked up though; restarting a bunch of stuff (alsa, pulseaudio) seems to have fixed it, at least for now.