# Facing problem while integrating voice assistant in rasa chatbot

Tags: text-to-speech, chatbot, voice-recognition, rasa-core, rasa

I was following [this tutorial](https://blog.rasa.com/how-to-build-a-voice-assistant-with-open-source-rasa-and-mozilla-tools/) to integrate voice assistant in my chatbot. When I was in the *Implementing the text-to-speech component* stage, I have downloaded `deepspeech_test_prediction.py` file and kept it inside `deepspeech_test_prediction.py` file and ran this command.

```
python deepspeech_test_prediction.py
```

After this, I am facing this error.

[image]

How can I solve this problem?

I had my headphone plugged in my device.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like your input/output audio device isn't being recognised properly by `pyaudio`. There's steps described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37063540/i-cant-run-a-simple-code-using-pyaudio-errno-9996-invalid-output-device-n) on how to check the config of `pyaudio`, and potential steps on how to resolve it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4672155/pyaudio-ioerror-no-default-input-device-available?rq=1)

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, I do not know the answer to this question, but have you tried asking your question on the [Rasa Forum](https://forum.rasa.com/)?

Comment: Yea but that didn't solve the problem. It would great if there were a YouTube tutorial about this voice integration.