# OSError: [Errno -9996] Invalid input device (no default output device) while trying to record audio with pyaudio in windows

Tags: python, pyaudio

i want to record my system audio with pyaudio (in python) but i'm getting this error :  OSError: [Errno -9996] Invalid input device (no default output device) please help me.
here is my code :

```
import pyaudio
import wave

CHUNK = 1024
FORMAT = pyaudio.paInt16
CHANNELS = 2
RATE = 44100
RECORD_SECONDS = 5
WAVE_OUTPUT_FILENAME = "output.wav"

p = pyaudio.PyAudio()

stream = p.open(format=FORMAT,
                channels=CHANNELS,
                rate=RATE,
                input=True,
                frames_per_buffer=CHUNK)

print("* recording")

frames = []

for i in range(0, int(RATE / CHUNK * RECORD_SECONDS)):
    data = stream.read(CHUNK)
    frames.append(data)

print("* done recording")

stream.stop_stream()
stream.close()
p.terminate()

wf = wave.open(WAVE_OUTPUT_FILENAME, 'wb')
wf.setnchannels(CHANNELS)
wf.setsampwidth(p.get_sample_size(FORMAT))
wf.setframerate(RATE)
wf.writeframes(b''.join(frames))
wf.close()
```

here is full stacktrace :

```
C:\jagdish\JKRecorder> & C:/Users/mohit/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python39/python.exe c:/jagdish/JKRecorder/temp.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\jagdish\JKRecorder\temp.py", line 13, in <module>
    stream = p.open(format=FORMAT,
  File "C:\Users\mohit\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pyaudio.py", line 750, in open    
    stream = Stream(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\mohit\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pyaudio.py", line 441, in __init__
    self._stream = pa.open(**arguments)
OSError: [Errno -9996] Invalid input device (no default output device)
C:\jagdish\JKRecorder>
```

Comment: i'm using windows

Comment: Please provide the full stacktrace

Comment: I've updated the question with full stacktrace

Comment: Does this answer your question? [I can't run a simple code using pyaudio - \[Errno -9996\] Invalid output device (no default output device)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37063540/i-cant-run-a-simple-code-using-pyaudio-errno-9996-invalid-output-device-n)