# OSError: No Default Input Device Available

Tags: python, speech-recognition

I am trying speech recognition with SpeechRecognition package in python and facing problem when trying to work with microphone.

I tested Microphone of my earphones , it is working fine and is being detected by my computer but my script is throwing error as if there is no mic connected.
When I run the following script after installing pyAudio

```
$python -m speech_recognition
```

I get following error:

```
  Traceback (most recent call last):

   File "/home/harshita/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
        "__main__", mod_spec)

    File "/home/harshita/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
        exec(code, run_globals)

    File "/home/harshita/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/speech_recognition/__main__.py", line 4, in <module>
        m = sr.Microphone()

    File "/home/harshita/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/speech_recognition/__init__.py", line 86, in __init__
        device_info = audio.get_device_info_by_index(device_index) if device_index is not None else audio.get_default_input_device_info()

    File "/home/harshita/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyaudio.py", line 949, in get_default_input_device_info
        device_index = pa.get_default_input_device()

    OSError: No Default Input Device Available
```

And also:

> > > import speech_recognition as sr
> > >
> > > sr.Microphone.list_microphone_names()

output:
[ ]

Where is it that I am going wrong?

Also why is it showing 'OSError'?, I saw other related queries but all of them had it as IOError.

Comment: It clearly says `OSError: No Default Input Device Available`, means  thre needs an input device for your module which you trying to run.

Comment: Ya right but i have my input device connected,I get this error in spite of this fact.

Comment: You also need to properly configure the driver (alsa)

Comment: @NikolayShmyrev How can I  check if alsa is configured properly or not. I checked that alsa is installed with following version: Advanced Linux Sound Architecture Driver Version k4.4.0-45-generic.

Comment: Alsa is properly configured if you can record audio with arecord tool.

Comment: Ya I just checked, I was able to record using arecord and then play it using aplay.

Comment: This is highly unlikely, what command are you using for recording

Comment: this one to record:   $ arecord -d 10 /tmp/test-mic.wav

Answer (score 1):

At first(as for Linux users), check the following [link](https://github.com/ContinuumIO/anaconda-issues/issues/4139#issuecomment-433710003) and update your Pyaudio & Portaudio with the given repository, since there is a bug in Anaconda's Pyaudio and Portaudio library.

Now if it worked, but the terminal is stuck on "Speak anything..", then it means that the library is detecting too many noises, and you can filter them out by adding the following line after the `with` statement.

```
r.adjust_for_ambient_noise(source)
```

For example:

```
with sr.Microphone(device_index=2) as source:
    r.adjust_for_ambient_noise(source)
    print("Speak Anything :")
    audio = r.listen(source)
```

Please note the `r` here is the instance of speech_recognition.Microphone().

Also, I recommend you start passing the index of the the device you want to use like I did in the above example (like this `device_index=2`), and you could try using an index with range of 0 to 4 (could be more or less, depends on how many inputs you have).