# SpeechRecognition producing OSError: No Default Input Device Available

Tags: python, python-3.6, speech-recognition, pyaudio

This:

```
import speech_recognition as sr

r = sr.Recognizer()
with sr.Microphone() as source:
    print("Speak Anything :")
    audio = r.listen(source)
    try:
        text = r.recognize_google(audio)
        print("You said : {}".format(text))
    except:
        print("Sorry could not recognize what you said")
```

Producing this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "magic.py", line 5, in <module>
    with sr.Microphone() as source:
  File "/home/myPorfile/anaconda3/envs/customEnv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/speech_recognition/__init__.py", line 86, in __init__
    device_info = audio.get_device_info_by_index(device_index) if device_index is not None else audio.get_default_input_device_info()
  File "/home/myPorfile/anaconda3/envs/customEnv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyaudio.py", line 949, in get_default_input_device_info
    device_index = pa.get_default_input_device()
OSError: No Default Input Device Available
```

Apparently Pyaudio is not detecting my Earphone nor my computer's mic.

`sr.Microphone.list_microphone_names()` verifying that by returning an empty list `[]`.

I also tried installing Pyaudio and portaudio.

Using: Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS / python 3.6

Comment: The following steps worked for me here https://stackoverflow.com/a/56104529/8599711