# OSError: No Default Input Device Available (PyAudio)

Tags: python, ubuntu, flask, pyaudio

I am using [this Github repo](https://github.com/x4nth055/pythoncode-tutorials/tree/master/machine-learning/speech-emotion-recognition) to guide me in my process to create a Flask application that can detect your mood via your voice. To build the application I was on Windows 10 using Pycharm and Python 3.6. Everything works fine and I have no issues as you can see with this output: [successful output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aIDfV.png).

My problems arise when I clone my app to my Ubuntu subsystem on my Windows machine or my Google VM running Ubuntu 18. When I try to record my voice I get this error: `OSError: [Errno -9996] Invalid output device (no default output device)` ([full error here](https://pastebin.com/i6HmPfPc)).

I have seen [this Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4672155/pyaudio-ioerror-no-default-input-device-available) post get linked many times when encountering this error but none of the answers fixed my issue.

When I run this code

```
>>> import pyaudio
>>> pa = pyaudio.PyAudio()
>>> pa.get_default_input_device_info()
```

I get this ouput

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/ian/app/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyaudio.py", line 949, in get_default_input_device_info
    device_index = pa.get_default_input_device()
OSError: No Default Input Device Available
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53058689/oserror-no-default-input-device-available

Comment: @BillChen I didnt use Anaconda to install pyaudio.